# How show Captcha in jquery.dialog

Tags: jquery, yii, capture

If I want to show Captcha in Yii 1.1.14 I write something like :

```
<?php if(CCaptcha::checkRequirements()): ?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
        <div>
            <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My question is if can I show similar Captcha with popup page (I use jquery.dialog for this) as in this I do not have $form object ?
Actually I would like to use CCaptcha class, but not use some other captcha library, as I want to have similar captcha in different parts of site.

Answer (score 0):

1. For popup dialog i've created an absolute positioned window popping up thru js scripting. I center it thru js as well.
   This window is easily might be filed with any form. This is ideally fits for the login.registration page.
2. Other option is that you CAN fill popup window with a form. I use `zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog` (sorry if poor formatted):

   beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
   'id'=>'cart',
   // additional javascript options for the dialog plugin
   'options'=>array(
       'title'=>Yii::t('general','Add the assortment to a cart'),
       'autoOpen'=>false,
   ),
   ));

    echo Yii::t('general', 'Enter the amount of this assortment item');?>

   beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
   'id'=>'assortment-form',
   'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
   'method'=>'post',
   'htmlOptions' => array(
      // 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
   ),
   )); ?>
       hiddenField($model,'id'); ?>
    
       labelEx($model,'amount'); ?>
       widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
               'model'=> $model,
               'attribute'=> 'amount',
               'data' => $data,
               'options'=> array(
                   'allowClear'=>true, 
                   'width' => '100', 
                   'placeholder' => '',
                   //'minimumInputLength' => 3
                   ),
           )); 
       //echo $form->error($model, 'amount'); ?>



   'btn btn-medium btn-primary', 'style'=> 'float:right;')); ?>


   endWidget(); ?>

   $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
   /******************************** end of the Dialog box *************************************/

Second option i did not try with captcha, yet you might do it.